# Why is "margarine" pronounced with a soft "g"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

As far as I know, *margarine* is the only word in which a 'g' is pronounced as 'j' though it is *not* followed by 'e', 'i', or 'y'.  What causes the unorthodox pronunciation?

Comment: i suspect its to do with it's French origins

Comment: But then why aren't there many other French loanwords which have a soft 'g' followed by 'a'?  Why is this the only one?  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/margarine) says _Margaret_ comes from the same place as _margarine_, and _it_ doesn't have a soft 'g'.

Comment: French words with *ga*, including *margarine*, have a hard *g*. So, that's not the reason.

Comment: mortgage has French origins, and the agent noun form is `mortgagor` which is another soft 'g' example

Comment: What's really interesting is that the original word *[margarin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/margarin)* is pronounced with a hard 'g', at least in English.  There doesn't seem to be room for a soft 'g' anywhere in the etymology.

Comment: @JoseK: Nice!  Though the reason for the soft 'g' seems slightly more obvious in that case.

Comment: @F'x: and drm: I did not know the orignal French pronunciation was hard 'g' I admit

Comment: @JoseK: my dictionary report *mortgagor*, like *mortgage*, to have a hard *g* in both UK and US pronunciation. Do you have any evidence to back your claim?

Comment: @F'x: He was referring to the second 'g', which is followed by 'o' in *mortgagor*, but remains soft. (There's also *obligor* and *pledgor*, along the same lines.)

Comment: The only word? How about judgment and its derivatives?

Comment: @David Halperin - isn't judgment itself a derivative of judge?

Comment: Yes, but it still counts.  Same as *mortgagor* which derives from *mortgage*.

Comment: What @Waggers is probably saying is that, rather than saying "judgment and its derivatives," it could have been better to say "judge and its derivatives."

Comment: I would have said "judgment and similar forms".

Comment: **the only one**?  I like the word "gaol" myself.

Comment: I don't think "_judge_" is really considerable, since the G is pronounced as /dʒ/ before E, I and something else I can't remember... The "problem" here is that the G is still followed by A or O but still pronounced as /dʒ/.

Comment: Only **marginally** relevant, perhaps, but I think this word is basically from Latin. I'm not aware it spent a long time in France before reaching Britain.

Comment: @Alenanno: E, I, and Y.

Comment: @drm65 ah yes, that one lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OED says:

> N.E.D. (1905    ) gives as the pronunciation only (mā·ɹgărīn), with  /-g-/ ; this pronunciation, which became rare in the second half of the 20th cent., probably underlies the nickname Maggie Ann (see maggie n. 4). N.E.D. (1902    ), however, s.v. Oleomargarine, notes that the latter is ‘Often mispronounced (-mā·ɹdʒərīn), as if spelt -margerine’ (i.e. with  /-dʒ-/ ). The latter pronunciation is recorded in 1913 (with subordinate status) by H. Michaelis & D. Jones Phonetic Dict. Eng. Lang.; the shortened form marge, in which -ge also implies pronunciation with  /-dʒ-/ , is attested within ten years of this (see 1922 at marge n.2). The shift of stress, outside North American English, from the first to the final syllable is also first evidenced in the 1913 source.

I doubt if we will find any more definite answer than this.

Comment: this only hints that it was pronounced correct for some time and the current form was noted as mispronunciation... Or i got it all wrong. Anyway, the current pronunciation is extremely painful to anyone that sees the written word wout being exposed to the pronunciation first...

Comment: No, it says that one pronunciation was current for a while, and that another pronunciation (which at first was described as a mispronunciation) then took over.

Comment: isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: No because my comment does not contain the word "correct", which depending on its sense is either tautologous or tendentious.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *margarine* is pronounced thus because it is said to have been invented by [Hippolyte Mege-Mouries](http://www.trivia-library.com/a/history-and-story-behind-inventions-margarine.htm). As this gentleman was French, that would fix the soft-g pronunciation.

For more you could look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butter), or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyte_M%C3%A8ge-Mouri%C3%A9s).