# Can "ga" be pronounced with a soft "g"?

Tags: pronunciation

In a discussion about how one should pronounce *"algae"*, someone used the argument than in English, *"ga"* is never pronounced with a soft *"g"*. Is this true? On the moment I couldn't find any examples, even from latin origin.

Interestingly, according to [the wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/algae#Latin) the /ˈal.d͡ʒe/ pronunciation comes from Ecclesiastical Latin, while Classical Latin uses /ˈal.ɡae̯/. That means there could be more examples from Ecclesiastical Latin.

While researching I found [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36040/why-is-margarine-pronounced-with-a-soft-g), that only focuses on one word but still gives 2 examples, *"margarine"* and the dated *"gaol"*. Both seem to be exception. Are there other examples?

Is it correct to say that *"ga"* is *almost* never pronounced with a /dʒ/ in English?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. There is a specific question here about [margarine with a soft g](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36040/why-is-margarine-pronounced-with-a-soft-g) although it's not terribly conclusive. You explain "algae", and you can easily find the history of "gaol" [online](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/12/jail-gaol.html).

Comment: @StuartF My main question is "are the any other examples", which remains open.

Comment: *mar**ga**rine* is a soft g. I'm sure there will be other examples that don't rely on the "trick" of using ***ae*** (which in some typefaces and some words is a single character anyway).

Comment: *Is it correct to say that "ga" is almost never pronounced with a /dʒ/ in English?* In English, you will find that there are no cases of "always" and "never".

Comment: The name ["Gamal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamal) satisfies your requirement if you consider it "English".

Answer (score 3):

You ask: are there any other examples?

There's also [*epigaea*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Epigaea), the Latin genus name for *[trailing arbutus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigaea_repens)* (also called *mayflower*).

Like *algae*, this pronunciation arises from the Ecclesiastical Latin pronunciation of the Latin letter combination *gae*.

Comment: Yes, classical _ae_ /ai/ changed to /e/ in Vulgar Latin and later in medieval Latin, as well as the Romance languages. And before a front vowel, velars like /ɡ/ would palatalize in many words.